# Get uploaded image dimensions  using javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, forms, http-post

In one of my form ( jquery + html + php ) I have to check the extension of file before uploading to the server. ie. User is only allowed to upload `.jpg` files only and within fixed dimensions for eg: 150px X 100px. For this I will have to write a client-side validation using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that in Javascript. you have to use flash based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to do this.

**Update:**

There is one jquery upload project that I really like,

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: any alternate way for this with html5 ?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot check the true type of a file. This means that a user can upload a BMP file by renaming it to a jpg extension.

However a sample javascript code that can do the work is:

```
// Assume that filename is a variable that holds the filename 
if(filename.lastIndexOf(".jpg") == -1) {
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and actually I want to get the dimensions of the uploaded file at the time of form submit

Comment: As previsously stated, this cannot be done with pure javascript. You have to check a JavaScript library for this.